# Oracle pivot operator

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to oracle pivot. Is this possible?

I have two columns `Type` and `Value`

```
type     value
---------------
a        a1
b        b1
c        c1
etc
```

Will I be able to get something like this, all in a single row??

```
a   b    c 
a1  b1   c1
```

upon trying a query like this i am getting an output like this

```
  select A,B from tbl
  pivot (max(value) for type in ('a' as A,'b' as B))

  ------------------------------------
    A    B
   null  b1
   a1    null
```

Thanks

Comment: Are values in the `Type` the known set?

Comment: Yes, lets assume they are just a,b,c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting the output like that simply because you are issuing `select` statement against a table (your `tbl` table) which presumably contains a column(primary key column for instance) which uniquely identifies a row and `pivot` operator takes into consideration values of that column. Here is a simple example:

```
/*assume it's your table tbl */
with tbl(unique_col, col1, col2) as(
  select 1, 'a',  'a1' from dual union all
  select 2, 'b',  'b1' from dual union all
  select 3, 'c',  'c1' from dual
)
```

A query against such a table will give you that output(undesirable output) you provided in the question:

```
select A,B 
  from tbl
pivot(
  max(col2) for col1 in ('a' as A,'b' as B)
)
```

Result:

```
A    B
--   --
a1   null   
null b1
```

In order to produce desired output, you need to exclude the column with unique value for a row:

```
select A
     , B 
  from (select col1 
             , col2  /*selecting only those columns we are interested in*/
           from tbl ) 
  pivot(
    max(col2) for col1 in ('a' as A,'b' as B)
  )
```

Result:

```
A  B
-- --
a1 b1
```

Comment: Yes, that worked like a charm...Thanks for your detailed explanation to make me understand the difference!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
SELECT a, b, c
  FROM tbl
 PIVOT
 (
   MAX(Value) FOR Type IN ('a' as a, 
                           'b' as b, 
                           'c' as c)
 )
```

For more details you can refer to [this](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php) documentation.

Comment: i am not sure i understand the syntax... this is what i have: select 'a','b','c' from tbl pivot(max(value) for type in ('a','b','c'))