# Select multiple records as multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a table that look like this:

```
ID Name
-------
1  John
1  Mary
1  Jane
2  John 
2  Mary
3  Jane
```

Knowing that every ID can only contain up to three names, I want to use a `SELECT` statement to turn this into the following:

```
ID Name1 Name2 Name3
--------------------
1  John  Mary  Jane
2  John  Mary
3  Jane
```

Is there a way to do this in SQL?

Comment: Which db are you using? Oracle ?

Comment: You need to look at using a PIVOT, whose syntax is database-specific.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280591/oracle-pivot-operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that there are at most three names, you can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then name end) as name1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then name end) as name2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then name end) as name3
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by name) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

With Oracle, you can use the PIVOT feature.

However, you'll need to RANK your rows first, over id-name pairs, and then you can do the pivot directive for (literally) the rank you just generated.

Pages to read:

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html
- http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=506