# Vertical Data to Horizontal In Oracle Using PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I got stuck in one query. I have a vertical table where data is stored in below format :

```
FK_ID  Key Value
-----------------
1      Name  A
1      Sex   M
2      Name  B
2      Age   21
3      Name  C
3      Mob   123456789
```

And I want the data like this :

```
Name      Age    Sex    Mob
---------------------------
A         NULL   M      NULL
B         21     NULL   NULL
C         NULL   NULL   123456789
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [oracle-pivot-operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280591/oracle-pivot-operator)

Comment: how to achieve that. It will really be appreciated if you can help me in syntax as well.

Comment: Try read the linked question. [ORACLE PIVOT OPERATOR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280591/oracle-pivot-operator)

Comment: Not able to achieve that what I required.

Answer (score 1):

Group by the fk_id column and use CASE statement to filter out the keys as columns.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/3034)

**Query**:

```
with tab(fk_id, key_, value_) as (
  select 1, 'Name', 'A' from dual union all
  select 1, 'Sex', 'M' from dual union all
  select 2, 'Name', 'B' from dual union all
  select 2, 'Age', '21' from dual union all
  select 3, 'Name', 'C' from dual union all
  select 3, 'Mob', '123456789' from dual
  )
 select 
   max(case when key_ = 'Name' then value_ end) as "Name",
   max(case when key_ = 'Age' then value_ end) as "Age",
   max(case when key_ = 'Sex' then value_ end) as "Sex",
   max(case when key_ = 'Mob' then value_ end) as "Mob"
 from tab
 group by fk_id
 order by 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/3034/0)**:

```
| Name |    Age |    Sex |       Mob |
|------|--------|--------|-----------|
|    A | (null) |      M |    (null) |
|    B |     21 | (null) |    (null) |
|    C | (null) | (null) | 123456789 |
```

Or, use PIVOT.

```
with tab(fk_id, key_, value_) as (
  select 1, 'Name', 'A' from dual union all
  select 1, 'Sex', 'M' from dual union all
  select 2, 'Name', 'B' from dual union all
  select 2, 'Age', '21' from dual union all
  select 3, 'Name', 'C' from dual union all
  select 3, 'Mob', '123456789' from dual
  )
 select *
 from tab
 pivot( max(value_) for (key_) in ('Name','Age','Sex','Mob'))
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/3043/1)**:

```
| FK_ID | 'Name' |  'Age' |  'Sex' |     'Mob' |
|-------|--------|--------|--------|-----------|
|     1 |      A | (null) |      M |    (null) |
|     2 |      B |     21 | (null) |    (null) |
|     3 |      C | (null) | (null) | 123456789 |
```