# Select to get 3 rows of data to 3 different columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Table (TableA) with 3 columns (ColA,ColB,ColC)

ColA and ColB are Primary Keys

```
select *
from TableA
where ColA = '001';
```

gives me this

```
COLA COLB      COLC 
---- ----- -------- 
001  AA1        460  
001  AB1        380 
001  AC1        950
```

I need this result in this format

```
COLA         AA1          AB1         AC1
-----------  -----------  ----------- ----------- 
001          460          380         950
```

i.e all resulting rows into one column to different corresponding columns.

Comment: PIVOT is what you are looking for :).. https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1

Comment: Search for `pivot`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle pivot operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280591/oracle-pivot-operator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And the `PIVOT` version :

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        TableA
    WHERE ColA = '001'
)
PIVOT
(
    MAX(ColC)
    FOR ColB IN ('AA1','AB1','AC1')
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select 
COLA, 
max(case when COLB='AA1' then COLC end) as AA1
max(case when COLB='AB1' then COLC end) as AB1
max(case when COLB='AC1' then COLC end) as AC1
from table
group by COLA
```