# Mixed data values to field

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data in pl-sql:

```
super   stage   per
04031   BRICK   43
04031   BRIKF   31
04031   SLAB    27
04031   SSLAB   38
04123   BRICK   59
04123   ROOFF   59
04123   SITE    38
04221   BRICK   56
04221   ROOFF   64
04221   ROOFT   40
04221   SETS    100
04221   SITE    39
04221   SLAB    33
```

I want to make it so the data switches to have the stages as the header and the percentages as the values like so:

```
super BRICK BRICKF SLAB SSLAB ROOFF ROOFT SETS SITE
04031 43    31     27   38                  
04123 59                      59               38
04221 56           33         64    40    100  39
```

Comment: There are lots of answers on StackOverflow for pivoting in Oracle. [Find some here (link)](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=oracle+pivot). The main thing is whether the stages - the desired columns - are a fixed set or variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle pivot operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280591/oracle-pivot-operator)

Answer (score 0):

Try this method for Pivoting the table

```
select * from
(select super   , stage   , per from table) 
pivot(per for satge in ('BRICK', 'BRICKF', 'SLAB', 'SSLAB', 'ROOFF', 'ROOFT', 'SETS', 'SITE')
```